# Prestashop says employee doesn't exist even though it does

Tags: sql, prestashop

Sometime ago I moved a shop on PrestasShop 1.5 from one server to another. Today I tried to log in to my account, but it says that employee doesn't exist or password is incorrect.

I thought I must have changed the password than - so I used forgotten password option, but it told me that this user doen't exist...

So I logged in with my other account (without superadmin rights) to see if maybe the e-mail was wrong. But what I saw was the strangest thing: there were two employees listed: superadmin and testing account, but **in the e-mail field of the superadmin account there was the value of actual database name instead of valid e-mail**. I couldn't change that from admin panel because this user didn't have the rights to edit superadmin account.

But that's not all. **In testing account edit form there was superadmin's e-mail inserted instead of the one i actually logged in with...**

That's messed up!

So I went to my phpmyadmin to check what's going on. But there everything seems to be ok. E-mail addresses are correct. I even changed the superadmin password using this tutorial: http://paikialog.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/prestashop-generate-and-change-cookie-key/

Nothing works. But it's even worse now - testing account stopped working also. Changing it's password doesn't work. I cannot log in to admin panel at all.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may try changing the email id of the user from **phpmyadmin** and try forget password option from admin.